# React Konva move screen with two fingers on touchpad

Tags: react-konva, konvajs-reactjs

I'm looking for the correct event to navigate on the canvas with two fingers on touch pad. I'm using React Konva.js and I found a good example on the site https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Zooming_Relative_To_Pointer.html
The problem that I don't want to zoom in or out with the two fingers but navigate. Does anyone have a relevant example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

const shape = new Konva.Circle({
  x: stage.width() / 2,
  y: stage.height() / 2,
  radius: 50,
  fill: 'green'
});
layer.add(shape);

stage.on('wheel', (e) => {
  const dx = -e.evt.deltaX;
  const dy = -e.evt.deltaY;
  stage.x(stage.x() + dx);
  stage.y(stage.y() + dy);
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@^8/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete the great answer by @lavrton, you can add zoom trackpad support with:

```js
window.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.ctrlKey) { // special flag that's active while zooming
    scale -= e.deltaY * 0.01;
  } else {
    posX -= e.deltaX * 2;
    posY -= e.deltaY * 2;
  }

  render();
});

// gesture event with rotation is Safari only
window.addEventListener("gesturestart", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  startX = e.pageX - posX;
  startY = e.pageY - posY;
  gestureStartRotation = rotation;
  gestureStartScale = scale;
});

window.addEventListener("gesturechange", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  rotation = gestureStartRotation + e.rotation;
  scale = gestureStartScale * e.scale;

  posX = e.pageX - startX;
  posY = e.pageY - startY;

  render();

})

window.addEventListener("gestureend", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/multi-touch-trackpad-gesture?file=index.js

From: https://kenneth.io/post/detecting-multi-touch-trackpad-gestures-in-javascript

Would be nice to have it on the offical konva.js example site.